# How Do I Parse String into Double in C?

Tags: c, string, double

Currently, I am making a program that takes a user input (as a string of form: 2, 0.5, or 1/2), and I am sending this input to my parseFraction() function which will check to see if there are any "/" in the string and will convert to a double accordingly (by sub-stringing to the "/" for numerator and from "/"+1 to the end for denominator), then it will parse the numerator and denominator as doubles and divide them and return that number (unless if it doesn't have the "/", then it will just convert to double right then). I am a Java & Python Programmer learning C (5 weeks in), so I coded my program in both Java and Python to get these:

```java
//JAVA    
private static double parseFraction(String in) {
        double ret = 0.0;
        if(in.contains("/")) {
            ret = Double.parseDouble(in.substring(0,in.indexOf("/"))) / Double.parseDouble(in.substring(in.indexOf("/")+1, in.length()));
        }
        else {
            ret = Double.parseDouble(in);
        }
        return ret;
    }
```

```py
#Python
def parseFraction(inp):
    ret = 0.0
    if inp.count("/") > 0:
        ret = float(inp[0:inp.index("/")]) / float(inp[inp.index("/")+1: len(inp)])
    else:
        ret = float(inp)
    return ret
```

Basically all I need is a way to convert from String to Double and to Substring in C.

Comment: My guess is you are getting the downvotes, because you didn't even do 1 google search...

Answer (score 1):

`strtod()` in stdlib.h

From https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtod.htm:

**Declaration**

Following is the declaration for strtod() function.

`double strtod(const char *str, char **endptr)`

**Parameters**

`str` − This is the value to be converted to a string.

`endptr` − This is the reference to an already allocated object of type char*, whose value is set by the function to the next character in str after the numerical value.

**Return Value**

This function returns the converted floating point number as a double value, else zero value (0.0) is returned.

Answer (score 0):

This should be a job for `sscanf`:

```
double d1;
double d2;
double result;

int r = sscanf(str, "%lf/%lf", &d1, &d1);
if (r == 1)
  {
    /* First double was found, but not second double or '/' */
    result = d1;
  }
else if (r == 2)
  {
     /* Both doubles were found, with a '/' in between them. */
     result = d1/d2;
  }
else /* r == 0 || r == EOF */
  {
    /* No matching was done, should handle parse error */
  }
```

This is a very lax parser, probably accepting invalid input as valid. But an exact specification was not given, and depending on the use case, a lax parser may be acceptable.

I would also recommend considering using an existing data-format that already has a parser implementation you could use. This is especially important when parsing untrusted data and you have to be strict on what you accept.